# Kibana slow performance optimization

Tags: azure, performance, ubuntu, elk, kibana

I have a Kibana page which takes about 7-10 seconds to load.

Benchmarking same page shows ~1s to complete the request

```
$ ab -n 10 "http://kibana/app/discover#/view/15a67850-6921-11ea-8308-058e42e28132"
```

and the exact same query to elastic takes about 1s to complete as well.

```
$ ab -n 20 -p same-query.json -T application/json "http://kibana:9200/logstash*/_search"
```

It's just 2 simple `match` filters within a request to `logstash*` index.
Taking into account benchmarking above I don't think the the issue related to Elasticsearch/Logstash but rather to Kibana itself. So my questions are:

1. Is the a way to tune/optimize performance for Kibana (page loading time)?
2. In case I move Kibana UI to separate instance will that give any benefits to performance? (currently it's ELK stack on the one instance 8 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)
3. How can I additionally narrow down the exact reason of this slow performance?

Comment: What ELK version do you use ?

Comment: ELK version is 7.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically I've ended up turning these flags off (`/app/management/kibana/settings`)

```
filterEditor:suggestValues
discover:searchOnPageLoad
doc_table:highlight
visualize:enableLabs
telemetry:enabled
```

Other ideas I had in mind:

- adding nginx as a proxy caching all the static files (js for plugins / images)
- warmup script (periodically makes requests to predefined hot pages for Kibana to internally cache these pages) if that would work
- migrate to hosted cloud solution which might be optimized better for the loading time